# Pulling information from a Wordlist in Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to start off by saying that I am new to Visual Basic and am messing around with some elements out of curiousity to try and expand my knowledge. I am creating a Console Application in which I would like to do a "log in" application through command prompt. All's it is going to be is a "Please enter your username", and then I would like to have a list of names on a wordlist and then an IF and ELSEIF etc. to allow you to continue or not.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim txt As String
        txt = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\wordlist.txt")
        MsgBox(txt)

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username: ")
        Dim userName As String = Console.ReadLine()



    End Sub

End Module
```

That is all I have so far and have had a look around on the internet for some information but I can't seem to find any. If anyone has any help or any guidance that would be good thanks!

Regards,
Axe

Comment: Do you want to check if `txt` contains `userName`?

Comment: What is the format of your text file?  One word per line?  Comma separated? Etc...

Comment: It's one word per like and upper and lower case (Tom & tom)

Answer (score 0):

Load the text file into an array via ReadAllLines(), then you can do a check with Contains():

```
    Dim UserNames() As String
    UserNames = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\wordlist.txt")

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username: ")
    Dim userName As String = Console.ReadLine()
    If UserNames.Contains(userName) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome " & userName & "!")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("UserName not found: " & userName)
    End If
```

Comment: Just as I was writing mine on my phone. :). Well now he's got two answers. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim txt As New List (Of String)
    txt = ReadFileToList("C:\wordlist.txt")

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username: ")
    Dim userName As String = Console.ReadLine()

    If txt.IndexOf(userName) = -1 Then
        'Username does not exist
    Else
        'Username exists
    End If

End Sub

Private Function ReadFileToList(ByVal Path As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim Reader As New IO.StreamReader(Path)
    Dim Result As New List(Of String)

    Do Until Reader.EndOfStream
        Result.Add(Reader.ReadLine())
    Loop

    Reader.Close()
    Return Result
End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Did you know that you can populate the List by passing it the array from ReadAllLines()? `Dim txt As New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\wordlist.txt"))`

Comment: @Idle_Mind I do... But I prefer using StreamReader, since it's more customizable reading line by line, even though he's new to VB. But yeah... He can use the answer he want. :)